# Display/Edit a Currency in ASP.NET MVC Core, why so complicated?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

In an ASP.NET Core 2.0 application, I have a `Foo` class with **a lot** of classical string or numeric members and also a `int? Budget` field.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MyProj.ViewModels {
    public class RecordEditViewModel {
        public RecordEditViewModel() { }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Prop1 { get; set; }
        public string Prop2 { get; set; }
        public string Prop3 { get; set; }
        public string Prop4 { get; set; }    
        public string Prop5 { get; set; }

        /// <summary>The project budget</summary>        
        //[Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Must be a positive number")]
        [Display(Name = "Budget REVM"), 
         DataType(DataType.Currency), 
         DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "-", 
                       ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, 
                       DataFormatString = "{0:C}")]
        public int? Budget { get; set; }

        public string Prop6 { get; set; }
        public string Prop7 { get; set; }
        public string Prop8 { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }    
        public string Prop9 { get; set; }
        public string Prop10 { get; set; }        
        public string Prop11 { get; set; }    
        [Display(Name = "Attachments"), UIHint("IFromFile")]
        public IEnumerable<IFormFile> Attachments { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I want to
a) display it in the `14 000 €` format
b) edit it in the `14 000 €` format

this is a classic behavior, display/edit a currency in the currency format, but is seems hard to implement in the latest Microsoft .NET Framework.

a) `CustomModelBinder`? Should rewrite a binder for all the rest of the fields, but I need only the Budget
b) `TypeConverter`?
c) `DataType(DataType.Currency)`? does not seem to work in edit mode (not in display for int?)

My view:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <label asp-for="Budget" class="control-label"></label>
    <div>
        <input asp-for="Budget" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Budget" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not. Nothing changed in the way formatting is done either - there's no "classic" and "new" behaviour. No need for binders or converters at all - formatting is a job for the *view* anyway. Post your code. Right now it's impossible to guess what you refer to or what you even mean by `classic`.

Comment: Use a `[DisplayFormat]` attribute to display the formatted value. But you will need a custom ModelBinder to bind when you submit (a value of `14 000 €` cannot be converted to an `int`), and you will need to reconfigure the `$.validator` for client side validation. You might consider [this plugin](https://github.com/stephenmuecke/mvc-numericinput)

Comment: It's best to use a class to represent money. If it's just a decimal then you need another property for currency. You can have corresponding pairs of amount/currency properties everywhere but since they're intrinsically related it's better for them to be in one class. Plus you can have rounding rules built into the type. If you just have decimals you have to hope that any developer who ever makes changes follows the same rounding rules.

Comment: @Serge that doesn't explain anything. *Properties* don't have formats. The page formats the contents of the properties. It may use attributes placed on the properties or not. You may be using String.Format, `HtmlHelpers.DisplayFor` or `TextFor`. Or something else. It's impossible to help since you haven't explained what you use, what you try to do, what changed or what the problem is

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I updated the code, have a look

Comment: You use *tag helpers*. Html Helpers are still available. `asp-for` is equivalent to the `Html.TextFor` which *doesn't* use the `DisplayFormat` attribute. The format is used by `Html.DisplayFor` and `Html.EditorFor` which are still available. Check the "HTML Helper alternatives to Input Tag Helper" section in [Introduction to using tag helpers in forms in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms#the-input-tag-helper)

Comment: The [InputTagHelper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.taghelpers.inputtaghelper?view=aspnetcore-2.0) also has a `Format` property. You should be able to add `asp-format="{0:C}"` to your code

Comment: I used tag helpers because is something more readable as HtmlHelpers. `asp-format` really helped, however the edited value can't be saved with the € symbol

Comment: The tag helpers don't affect *binding*. Someone opened [a relevant issue on Github](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/6430) which was closed with this explanation. Html.EditorFor is still available. And I can't believe what I had to do to find about `asp-format`

Comment: The issue's closing comment: `The recommended solution here is to place the currency indicator outside of the editable field (e.g. before or after)`

Answer (score 14):

I noticed that [InputTagHelper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.taghelpers.inputtaghelper?view=aspnetcore-2.0) has a [Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.taghelpers.inputtaghelper.format?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_TagHelpers_InputTagHelper_Format) property, which means one can write :

```
<input asp-for="Budget" asp-format="{0:C}" class="form-control" />
```

Finding that though was *not* easy. It wasn't mentioned in the [Input Tag Helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms#the-input-tag-helper) section of the intro. In the end I found it through [ASP.NET Core MVC Input Tag Helper Deep Dive](https://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2015/05/13/mvc6-input-tag-helper-deep-dive.aspx)

Now I understand why people say ASP.NET Core's documentation is lacking - the intro goes to great lenghts to explain the various tag helpers in a single article, explains their relation to HTML Helpers, but *ommits* significant properties like `Format`. Without direct link to the class's documentation, it takes a bit of digging to find it.

There are quite a few similar questions in SO with answers that say "you can't format" or propose custom solutions.

**UPDATE**

An [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/6430) was opened on July 2017 about POSTing currency values that included a currency symbol. The thread is insteresting as it explains that `asp-format` only affects display, so the recommended solution is to put the symbol outside the `input`, possibly using Bootstrap input groups :

> The recommended solution here is to place the currency indicator outside of the editable field (e.g. before or after)

Perhaps something like this:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input asp-for="Budget" asp-format="{0:#,###.00}" class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">€</span>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, I appreciate your research! 
Now as the Budget is an `int`, I probably could use `{0:#,###}`... I find out I have additional handicap user could put in the field €, $, £ etc... or nothing at all.. in the field... in that case better probably is to use a regex...

Answer (score 0):

My biggest finding was to ensure you are not just rendering the field via your own  tag within the .cshtml; rather, ensure you are using the @Html.EditorFor() syntax to render the field:

```
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.AmountPaid)
                    <span asp-validation-for="AmountPaid" class="text-danger" />
                </div>
```

Once I used this, the validation worked correctly.  You can also decorate your field, such as:

```
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18, 2)")]
    public decimal AmountPaid { get; set; }
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.2