# Client Validation Error With Input Fields Containing Currency Values

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, code-first

I'm developing a web app using Asp.Net Core 2.1 and Code First.I've got a bunch of properties of type decimal and decorated them with the following attribute:

```
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C0}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

The problem is when the form goes in edit mode,the client validation throws the following error since the input field contains the currency symbol:

> The field must be a number.

How can I tell asp.net core to treat an input field with currency symbol as decimal value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display/Edit a Currency in ASP.NET MVC Core, why so complicated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48205531/display-edit-a-currency-in-asp-net-mvc-core-why-so-complicated)

Comment: Thanks,but the solution pointed out in the link isn't convenient as you would have to put 'asp-format' tag in all inputs containing money values across your app.I'm looking for a way to set a formatting attribute above the property in class and have asp.net-core take care of displaying the value in the proper way across the application.

Comment: If you check the comments, they are discussing this, and you can't really solve this just by adding the DisplayFormat, they recommend to use bootsrap input group, to move the currency symbol out from the input. Or use some JavaScript plugin which can handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a [custom model binder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2#custom-model-binder-sample) which converted (say) "$15,481" back to a decimal .

The result you are looking for is to validate the input as currency rather than a decimal, but you may have other needs for scrubbing input before model binding takes place so you will use an interface that describes the Scrub action.

```
 public interface IScrubberAttribute
{
    object Scrub(string modelValue, out bool success);
}
```

Next ,Add `CurrencyScrubberAttribute` that will do the work of parsing the user input to see if it is a valid currency format. C#’s `decimal.TryParse` has an overload that takes a `NumberStyle` and `CultureInfo`, which is how to do the currency validation. You’ll notice this only works with US currency ($) at this time, but would just require setting CultureInfo to handle other currencies.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class CurrencyScrubberAttribute : Attribute, IScrubberAttribute
{
    private static NumberStyles _currencyStyle = NumberStyles.Currency;
    private CultureInfo _culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");

    public object Scrub(string modelValue, out bool success)
    {
        var modelDecimal = 0M;
        success = decimal.TryParse(
            modelValue,
            _currencyStyle,
            _culture,
            out modelDecimal
        );
        return modelDecimal;
    }
}
```

Using the new `CurrencyScrubberAttribute` like below:

```
 public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C0}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [CurrencyScrubber]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

Add a model binder.  In the case of a strongly typed model like Product, the **ComplexTypeModelBinderProvider** accepts the challenge, then creates a binder for each property.

```
 public class ScrubbingModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

        if (!context.Metadata.IsComplexType&&context.Metadata.PropertyName!=null)
        {
            // Look for scrubber attributes
            var propName = context.Metadata.PropertyName;
            var propInfo = context.Metadata.ContainerType.GetProperty(propName);

            // Only one scrubber attribute can be applied to each property
            var attribute = propInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(IScrubberAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault();
            if (attribute != null)
                return new ScrubbingModelBinder(context.Metadata.ModelType, attribute as IScrubberAttribute);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The model binder will be handling simple types that have an `IScrubberAttribute`, but if for any reason we aren’t going to deal with the binding we will pass it to a **SimpleTypeModelBinder** to handle it.

```
public class ScrubbingModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    IScrubberAttribute _attribute;
    SimpleTypeModelBinder _baseBinder;

    public ScrubbingModelBinder(Type type, IScrubberAttribute attribute)
    {
        if (type == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(type));

        _attribute = attribute as IScrubberAttribute;
        _baseBinder = new SimpleTypeModelBinder(type);
    }

    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));

        // Check the value sent in
        var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        if (valueProviderResult != ValueProviderResult.None)
        {
            bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(bindingContext.ModelName, valueProviderResult);

            // Attempt to scrub the input value
            var valueAsString = valueProviderResult.FirstValue;
            var success = true;
            var result = _attribute.Scrub(valueAsString, out success);
            if (success)
            {
                bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(result);
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        }
        // If we haven't handled it, then we'll let the base SimpleTypeModelBinder handle it
        return _baseBinder.BindModelAsync(bindingContext);
    }
}
```

Add it in ConfigureServices

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new ScrubbingModelBinderProvider());
        });
```

Comment: A copy of the answer to the same thread in Asp.Net forum! Anyway,It's sounds pretty complicated and I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score -1):

The currency text can be shown in a separate place and data can be shown in text box.

Here is code for the same.

In Model

```
 public class Test
{
        [Key]
        [MaxLength(30)]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C0}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public float? Cost { get; set; }


}
```

In View

```
@model CoreCodeFist.Models.Dataobj.Test
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}
<div class="row">    
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <form asp-action="Index">
            <h2>Test</h2>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">@string.Format("{0:C}", Model.Cost!=null?Model.Cost:0).FirstOrDefault()</span>
                <input asp-for="Cost" asp-format="{0}" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span asp-validation-for="Cost" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
            </form>
</div>

</div>
```

In Controller

```
//First Page Load Method In Initialize Model Because Cost Is Initialize
        public IActionResult Index()
        {

            return View(new Test());
        }
        //This Is Edit Method 
        public IActionResult Edit(float id)
        {
            Test t = new Test()
            {
                Cost = id
            };
            return View("Index",t);
        }
        //First Page Post Method
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(Test model)
        {
            return View(model);
        }
```