# ASP.NET CORE DataFormat is effecting Edit action

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In my project I have properties that I would like to be displayed in dollar format.In my class I have it set up to do so

```
public class Worker{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C0}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public double Rev {get;set;}

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C0}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public double Cost {get;set;}

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C0}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public double Profit {get;set;}
}
```

This works and displays properly however when I go to the edit page All of the info is displayed in this format and I have to change every field from the dollar sign to the `double` or I get an error. Here is a screenshot showing. [image]

Even if I want to change one field I have to rewrite every field from $50,000 to 50000.00. How can I fix it so in `Edit` I don't have to worry about fixing every field, and my dollar sign format will be displayed in `Index` or `Details` and so on? Here is my controller for `Edit`

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var worker = await _context.Workers.FindAsync(id);
        if (worker == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return View(worker);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Id,Rev,Cost,Profit")] Worker worker)
    {
        if (id != worker.Id)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                _context.Update(worker);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!WorkerExists(worker.Id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(worker);
    }
```

At this point I am not concerned whether the currency format is displayed in `edit` view or just a number. I just do not want to have to convert every field from currency to a number in order to save the updates on one single property. How can I get rid of this error? Either leaving in this format or in number format.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display/Edit a Currency in ASP.NET MVC Core, why so complicated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48205531/display-edit-a-currency-in-asp-net-mvc-core-why-so-complicated)

Comment: It makes me feel I should be looking in my `Edit` view possibly? However it did not completely solve my problem just gave me simple hints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Even if I want to change one field I have to rewrite every field from $50,000 to 50000.00. How can I fix it so in Edit I don't have to worry about fixing every field, and my dollar sign format will be displayed in Index or Details and so on?

IMO, you just need to set `ApplyFormatInEditMode=false` or remove it from model.

```
public class Worker
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C0}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
    public double Rev { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C0}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
    public double Cost { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C0}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
    public double Profit { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I feel like an idiot for not realizing that! That happens when you're exhausted I guess. The answer hides in plain sight! Thank you.